# References about the the development of the concept of mechanical work

Tags: terminology, classical-mechanics, energy

I'm looking for references about how the concept of *mechanical work* ("$\boldsymbol{F}\cdot\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{r}$") or the concept of mechanical power ("$\boldsymbol{F}\cdot\boldsymbol{v}$") came about and developed. Please note that I'm not asking about *virtual* work and its related principle, and that I'm asking for *references* rather than direct reports as [this question](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/6942/7231) asks.

I consulted Truesdell & Toupin's *The Classical Field Theories* (Springer 1960), which usually provides many historical references, and Dugas's *A History of Mechanics* (Griffon 1955), but I didn't find very much in either. I know of Jammer's *Concepts of Force*, but I found so many nonsensical statements in that book that I don't trust it anymore.

I'd be very grateful if you could share any other references you know. Thank you!

Comment: Also Pierre Duhem: *The Origins of Statics: The Sources of Physical Theory* (Springer 1991) offers interesting discussions and historical remaks, although it mainly focuses on virtual work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see :

- Agamenon Oliveira, [A History of the Work Concept: From Physics to Economics](https://books.google.it/books?id=JcLEBAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), Springer (2014).

Also interesting :

- Danilo Capecchi, [History of Virtual Work Laws: A History of Mechanics Prospective](https://books.google.it/books?id=8qUXV6lo8-wC&printsec=frontcover), Birkhauser (2012).

Comment: I see that Capecchi has also written several other interesting historical books. Thank you!